# Quick way to turn single-value array into variable in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, variable-assignment

Say I have an array which fetched a single row from my database via the PDO::FETCH_ASSOC method, which I would then assign to a variable like so:

```
$result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

`$result` now holds an array equal to the following:

```
Array ( 
  [id] => 42
)
```

So, to assign the value 'id' to a variable by itself, I then have to go:

```
$id = $result['id'];
```

Is there a quicker way to do this, or even better, to make sure the query result from my database is a variable rather than an array directly, assuming the query is always guaranteed to return 1 result?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick

```
$result = $stmt->fetchColumn();
```

Docs [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php) (just noticed Mark Baker also put it in his comment).

Answer (score 1):

in PHP >= 5.4, try

```
$result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)[0];
```

this is a guess, though, you have to test it.